# what's going in /usr/bin/gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I noticed that there were no processes named "`gnome-terminal`" although I was using so called "`gnome-terminal`" which was invoked by clicking the icon on the menu bar on desktop.

```
$ ps -au | grep gnome
cul8er    8763  0.1  0.8 554960 33268 pts/22   Sl   05:16   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server --app-id com.canonical.Terminal.AnAuzDeiSeoqQhlGKbPNPeHhAROwBwtP
cul8er    8771  0.0  0.0  14852  1832 pts/22   S    05:16   0:00 gnome-pty-helper
cul8er    8821  0.0  0.0  14656  2232 pts/23   S+   05:27   0:00 grep --color=auto gnome
```

So I typed `gnome-terminal &`. the output was the following:

```
$ gnome-terminal &
[2] 8865
$ 
[2]+  終了                  gnome-terminal
$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.UTF-8
```

This result seems to show that the process of `gnome-terminal` exited immediately when the terminal emulator was displayed.
If it is true, why can I see new terminal without a process associated to it?

So I checked the command `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ which gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
$ file /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

`gnome-terminal` is a `python` script.

I looked at it. I couldn't understand enough because I don't know `python`, however I noticed `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server --app-id`, which was shown in the output of `ps`, is related to this issue. But I don't know what does '`subprocess`' and '`Popen`' mean.

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server',
                           '--app-id',
                           name],
                          stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                         stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

If sub processes are invoked whenever `gnome-terminal` script runs, multiple processes should run when I open gnome-terminals. However it always seems that there is only one process `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server --app-id` in `ps`'s output.

What is going on while the script runs?

And where is the process that represents so called "`gnome-terminal`"?

OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: thanks. It is acutally  similar but my question wants a little more concrete answer.  I edited  more details what I think.

Comment: I understand, will retract my dupe- vote.

Comment: In 14.04 they used to have `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper` which is a perl script. I guess they've changed it to python.

Comment: @Serg Wasn't that script meant for those wishing to use `gnome-terminal` instead of `xterm`? IIRC that script translated `xterm` options to `gnome-terminal` ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The single process `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server` is the process handling all of your gnome-terminal windows.

The command `gnome-terminal` fires up `gnome-terminal-server` if it's not already running, or connects to the existing instance and asks it to open a new window.

If each invocation of the command `gnome-terminal` opened a new window itself and so each terminal window was handled by its own separate process, you wouldn't be able to drag-n-drop tabs across them. This is I belive the most important reason behind this design. There might be other reasons as well, I'm not sure.