# How to launch multiple Gnome-terminal windows in a shell script and continue only after these have finished

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal, sh

In a script, I want to launch a number of Gnome Terminal windows, and then proceed with the script only when the windows are closed.

I have a shell script containing:

```
command 1

gnome-terminal ./script 1
gnome-terminal ./script 2
gnome-terminal ./script 3

command 2
command 3
```

If i run it, all `gnome-terminal` commands are immediately executed, and then `command 2`  and then `command 3`   are executed. How can I make it so that `command 2` and `command 3`  only run after  all `gnome-terminal` commands have finished?

Comment: A command should run after the previous commands have finished. If that does not happen, there is a mistake somewhere. Based on the information you give, it is impossible to even guess what the mistake may be.

Comment: @vanadium in the case of `gnome-terminal` each invocation is likely just sending a DBUS request to an existing `gnome-terminal-server` process and then exiting - see for example [what's going in /usr/bin/gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702520/whats-going-in-usr-bin-gnome-terminal) and [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal)

Comment: @steeldriver, interesting but that would mean that all gnome-terminal commands complete immediately, proceeding to the fifth command. The question here, though, is that command 5 does not run - I expect it to run when all terminals have "finished", and with the added info, if terminal-server was already running when the script started, it would immediately handle all gnome-terminal commands and proceed to command5. Question and problem remains unclear to me.

Comment: OK, I start to see the light. Probably the question is that command 5 should run only after all terminals have been closed.

Comment: Yes @vanadium that the question,  any solution ?

Comment: The comand 5 shoud run after all  gnome-terminal comands finish, not only after ( gnome-terminal  comand 4).

Comment: So please edit your question and make it more clear there.

Comment: I have the solution, but I expect you to edit the question to make it more clear, and to remove sloppyness like "Gnome-terminal" (where it should be gnome-terminal) and "Comand" (why not make this `command`). This is not a user forum for your temporary problem, but a Q&A site that should be of interest to more users now and in the future. So we expect some care in preparing both questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal  --wait command` does the trick. (If it doesn't support the `--wait` option then it appeared in a later gnome-terminal version. I guess it's available since approximately Ubuntu 20.04.)

---

Let me mention, however, that I find it a very bad practice to open a terminal emulator (let alone more of them) from a shell script. You'll hardly find examples of this, especially in high quality code, code shared with others. (For starter: If you're not the sole user of your script, how would the terminal know which terminal emulator the user prefers? How would your eyes follow the random placement of that terminal? How would you examine the command's output if the terminal closes automatically?)

It's not your script's job.

Open your preferred terminal emulator manually, launching your preferred shell. You can do tons of things inside it, including running your script, which then already has a terminal underneath and doesn't have to bother with opening one. That is, design your script to be run exactly as all the other terminal-based scripts and tools do it on your system. Once your script is completed, you can examine its output in the terminal and you can perform subsequent operations there as well.

Optionally set up a terminal emulator profile that launches the given script automatically, or create a desktop icon that runs the given script inside a terminal (in that case your desktop environment launches the terminal with your script -- technically most likely it's backed up by a `.desktop` file with a `Terminal=true` line).

Comment: Good advice, but the --wait trick will not work as requested.

Comment: Based on the comments to the question itself, the problem consists of two parts. One is how to know if a particular `gnome-terminal` tab has completed, for that `--wait` is the solution as far as I can tell. The other part is how to run three commands in parallel and wait for _all_ of them to complete, the answer is run them in the background with `&` and then run the `wait` shell builtin.

Comment: Add that part also to your answer and you will have been more than complete (including the advice).

Comment: Gonna be tricky to phrase properly, since the desired behavior is to open three terminal windows (or tabs?) which is incompatible with my advice :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect you are looking for, i.e., spawning several Gnome Terminal windows, and only continue the script once all of these windows are terminated, use the following construct:

```
...
gnome-terminal --wait -- command 1 &
gnome-terminal --wait -- command 2 &
gnome-terminal --wait -- command 3 &
wait
command 4
```

*Some explanation*: Gnome terminal works with a server/client system, which is why "gnome-terminal" commands normally release the terminal immediately. The `--wait` option will cause the terminal to wait  until its child process exits. That would then cause the script to wait as well, unless we send the process to the background appending the ampersand `&`.

Then we use the shell build-in `wait`. This causes the shell to wait until all processed to be finished. Thus, the script will proceed only when all of the terminals have been closed.

Comment: Hello,  it does not work, maybe because the gnome-terminal comands run an other shell using    (. / comand)

Comment: That is the idea. As long as something is happening in the other terminals, command 4 will not work, unless I misunderstood your intentions again? Mind I tested this myself. You do not provide details, so specific analysis is not possible. Please accept current answer and ask about a specific unexpected behavior in a dedicated question.